# Why are apps divided into Intel or M1 based types if universal binaries exist?

Tags: cpu, apple-silicon

So, I am downloading software in preparation for a M1 Macbook and I have quickly discovered that sites will often ask what type of mac chip you have along with an [article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211814) showing how.

On average, most sites (like [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-macosx.html)) I've seen will often have you pick from one of these options:

- Intel-based
- M1 Chip
- Universal Binary

The main question I have is why do these sites separate their apps into the two categories based off of your chip type if they can just push out universal binaries?

Other questions that stem from this are pretty much around why does *this* app only supports `X` chip types? - Somewhat similar to saying 'This program is designed to work on `AMD` cpus but not `Intel` cpus.'

Comment: Since we don’t entertain a question why Apple does things without a practical implementation. What is your practical decision you face here? What will people answering this help you do?

Comment: Note that for some of us, the terms 'Universal Binary' & 'Rosetta' are not new concepts - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_binary

Comment: The title of this question (has it been edited?) is misleading. The question is not 'why do different types of binary exist' (which most of the answers seem to address); but 'is there a reason why some devs use separate builds for different architectures instead of Universal Binaries'.

Comment: Are you sure you mean AMD, not ARM?  It's *extremely* rare to have a program that only works on AMD CPUs, but not Intel, and the only AMD Macs are home-built Hackintoshes.  Software that could only run on AMD would most likely be a CPU temperature monitor or power management tool, or something else specific to managing hardware (CPU or motherboard / chipset).  Otherwise, you could imagine something written to use AMD-only extensions like XOP and FMA4 (supported in Bulldozer-family) or 3DNow! way back in the day on K6 (single-precision FP in MMX registers, before SSE1), with no fallback code.

Comment: @Peter Cordes, I suspect OP is just unaware that AMD chips are using the same architecture/instruction set as Intels.

Comment: It's just for knowledge. The question will simply help me understand why different binaries exist in the first place. Title will be updated. For the AMD vs. Intel comment; it's an exaggeration. I wasn't aware of the fact that they use same instructions either ^

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My experience is that VLC is an outlier: most developers produce one Universal Binary app for both architectures, and that's what Apple recommends.

The only benefit to the user is one of file size. A Universal Binary contains 'the other' binary that your hardware can't use, so it's going to be around twice the size that you need.

There's more work for the developer in maintaining separate builds. However, it's possible that cross-platform software (written for Windows, Linuxes and MacOS) has systems in place to handle producing different builds from the same code, so they're geared up to do that anyway.

Ultimately, *why* a dev does something is a question only they can answer.

Comment: Google Chrome also is available in two platform-specific versions.

Comment: @nohillside Yes, I'm sure there are others. But I'd suggest they are in the minority of software for MacOS.

Comment: I surely hope so, yes :-)

Comment: One needs to point out that ONLY THE EXECUTABLE is roughly twice the size. All external resources (Images, User-Interface definitions, Text tables, Audio and Video) only appear once for both architectures.

Comment: There are good reasons to produce separate builds. If you use general C++ libraries you find often that they are impossible to build straight as universal binaries and i'm looking at big fishes like boost or icu.  Because the build process for others systems (windows with intel/arm or linux with many different) doesn't know universal binaries it's good to reuse what already there. But i have no idea why developers who produce universal binaries than also publish the architecture specific builds.

Answer (score 2):

> The main question I have is why do these sites separate their apps into the two categories based off of your chip type if they can just push out universal binaries?

While it is a easy (and recommended by Apple) way, it increases the size of the program. Because it is actually both of the installers under a single wrapper.

> Other questions that stem from this are pretty much around why does this app only supports X chip types? - Somewhat similar to saying 'This program is designed to work on AMD cpus but not Intel cpus.'

The comparison of AMD and Intel and Intel and M1 is between Red Delicious and Golden Delicious and Apple and Orange. What Apple say to be Intel is actually x86 ( amd64/x86-64 to be precise) ISA. AMD and Intel are just different manufacturers. Only programs to claim support for one if it is something to do with chipset or such low-level vendor-depndent harware part or vendor developed  features (3DNow!, AMD-V, Vt-x). There are many hackintosh in the wild running on AMD. M1, on the other hand, is designed by Apple in-house, based on ARM ISA. So, they are incompatible. They does things differently at machine code level.

Comment: I was trying to adjust your fruit analogy to match the standard vendor colours: Intel = blue, AMD = red (or sometimes green), but there aren't any blue apples, and there's nothing else a different colour than blueberries but tasting almost exactly the same.  But yeah, Red Delicious apple for AMD works.  (AMD used to be green, but after buying ATI graphics, they adopted its red, since NVidia was already green.)

Comment: This is simply not true. A Universal deployment is NOT a packaging of "Intel" app and "M1" app. It is rather a single application, with all the resources appearing only once, and about twice-sized executable binary.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple and straightforward. Network transfer size, and hard-drive footprint.

A Universal binary contains BOTH executable code (machine language) for the M1 processor, and for the intel X86-64 processor. This means that the overall app "bundle" will weigh much more. Most resources of an app will only need to appear once - (UI definitions, Images, Sounds, icons etc.) but the actual executable code - will be twice as large.

For big applications like VLC or Google-Chrome - this means tens to hundreds of megabytes extra.

We also remember that we're in the SSD era, and most Macs (especially low-end MacBooks) only sport 256GB to 1TB internal drive. Accumulating apps make a big difference.

So - thinking about download time and network transfer quotas (which cost the software supplier), and caring that on a users drive the apps won't take up too much -

Many software distributors offer the choice between Universal, intel-only and M1-only builds of the same apps.

It's as simple as that. Download what fits you, your Mac and your hard drive...

Comment: However Universal binaries started at a time when a 1GB disk was large and that had 4 architectures in each binary so size is not really a major factor.

Comment: But binary sizes got much bigger, because of the frequent use of huge open-source repositories, higher-level abstractions and "engines" of all sorts. Also Swift brought in lots of "runtime" code into your binary. I programmed for the first PPC Macs where "Fat" binaries were introduced, as well as for the first iPhone.  1GB drive is a still a huge in my opinion. But reality is no useful app today uses less than 10-20MB of executable alone (some take 300MB and more).

Comment: fat was introduced 10 years before PPC macs on NeXT 1GB drive ios small - the smallest you can get is probably 64G and that is a cheap SSD - Hard drives are at least 500G

Comment: Not sure you're correct - CFM (CodeFragmentManager) on MacOS classic did the same trick for PPC's on MacOS classic. the "Fat" macho format on NextStep didn't really got to too many machines at the time.

Answer (score -2):

Developers *could* only distribute universal binaries, but that might make life more difficult for superusers and system administrators who want to install the software, for example, on a fleet of Intel-based Macs without having to download two binaries (although they are packaged into one).

Some apps only support certain chip types because of how they are built/compiled. When someone writes the code for an application, they use a compiler to translate the high-level (human-readable) code into low-level, binary (ones and zeros) instructions that the computer can understand. Because different CPUs (e.g., AMD vs. ARM—M1 is an ARM chip) use different sequences of ones and zeros for the same actions, the same binary code will not work across all systems. To give a *very oversimplified* example (this is **not** actually how it works, and the binary numbers that I used are made up, but it illustrates the concept), an ARM CPU might interpret the instruction `10011100` as a command to write to RAM, but an Intel CPU might use the instruction `10001111` to write to RAM. If you feed an Intel CPU the instruction for the ARM CPU (`10011100`), it will probably perform an entirely different task. If the processor isn't doing what the compiler intended, then the app won't work.
To make apps work across multiple chip architectures, you need to compile separate binaries for each architecture (as each one has its own *instruction set*). This is why you are seeing the three options on some of the sites you visit.

Comment: The beauty of universal binaries is that they contain both the Intel and the ARM binary, so there is only one download and one deployment required.

Comment: If you build an app using normal Apple tools ie Xcode all the developer has to do is make a choice from a dropdown box of Arm, Intel or Universal. If Universal each object file/executable will run across all systems.

Comment: Strange that you mention AMD vs. ARM when Apple has never sold any AMD Macs.  It's x86 vs. ARM.  (AMD and Intel *are* machine-code compatible).  But yes that's why executable file formats (like MachO64) have metadata to specify what ISA their machine code is for, so trying to run an ARM binary on an x86 system will just error, instead of feeding the x86 CPU that binary machine code.  (I know you said your examples are made-up, but AArch64 (aka ARM64) machine code uses fixed-width 4-byte instructions (32 bits).  x86-64 instructions are variable length, and yes some are as short as one byte.)

Comment: @PeterCordes The 64 bit extensions to x86 were originally developed by AMD under the name AMD64. Therefore many systems, including Windows, BSD, parts of LLVM call the architecture AMD64.

Comment: @user71659: You think maybe this answer is mixing up AMD64 vs. ARM64 ISA names with AMD vs. ARM *vendor* names?  I guess that's possible, but it's still a mistake to refer to [AMD64 / Intel64 / x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53364320/the-most-correct-way-to-refer-to-32-bit-and-64-bit-versions-of-programs) as "AMD" if that's what's going on.  Unlike with ARM, there's no established usage of using the company name that architected the ISA to refer to the ISA itself.  (I'd still argue against using "ARM" to name AArch64 aka ARM64, but I know that is common usage.)

Comment: @PeterCordes The point of the examples (AMD and ARM) was to give an example of *why* compiling for different architectures is necessary. I'm not saying that Apple sells AMD Macs&mdash;the answer is just trying to explain why some apps only work on different architectures.

Also, it's important to remember that the MacOS operating system can be installed on computers that are not manufactured by Apple.

Comment: But there is no architecture called "AMD".  If you mean x86-64 aka AMD64, say that or just "x86", that was my point.  Or did you really mean something like `gcc -march=znver2 -O3` to tune for AMD Zen 2 when targeting x86-64 (and use the ISA extensions available on that specific microarchitecture, e.g. FMA, AVX2, and BMI2)?  If so, that's once again a weird thing to write on a Mac site.

Comment: And yes, I think I've read that Hackintosh systems are maybe possible on AMD hardware, but IIRC even harder to get working than on Intel because they have different chipsets than any officially supported Mac.  So drivers are a problem.  Doesn't seem super relevant, except to reinforce my point that "AMD" is *not* a different architecture from x86-64 generically or Intel's implementation of it in particular, because that's precisely why Apple binaries will work on that hardware.